# Test plan tracking - are there any good ones?

Tags: testing

We have a lot of test plans that have to be run every quarter. About half of them must be run manually. The rest are set up with Selenium. For the manual ones, we have each test case and it's steps in Excel spreadsheet *shudder*. It's really not an idea situation, so I'm looking for something that would allow us to enter the test plan steps into a test plan tracking application/database that our QA team can use to manage each of the test plans.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Try TestLink ... open source and its awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try Test Manager(Microsoft Product)